# particle keeps hanging in air when rendering in sheep it

Tags: rendering

[image]

I'm trying to render my project in sheep it render farm , but seems that when i render , the particle systems seem to keep hanging in the air where it should not stay. It is supposed to come in front of the vehicle as a dust cloud .  I have baked it in "bake all" , and baked it as a single object, but i have now tried 3 to render it in sheep it , and the particles keep hanging in the air. 
Is there a possibility to render the particles separately with a render layer later or any other mean to get it to work .

Comment: are you using the same version of blender for your scene than the one used in sheep it?

Comment: the version is the same,, but now i wonder that could it be that i should enable the sheep to allow gpu rendering ,, seems that it´s not on . ???would that make the difference ..

Comment: no it won't. There's something else going on here. may be look at the hash of the blender build and compared between the two: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPtq9.png

Comment: hash´s are identical 5bd8ac9 .

Comment: and this is rendering fine on your blender instance right?

Comment: Yes , when i made test renders with the same file that i send to sheep it i don´t get the problem and it renders alsow the second particle system, not seen in the sheep it render and this picture, it sould be on the back of the vehicle! so the other particle seems to disapier and the other is in wrong place . the Bake says it has 900 frames in .....

Comment: Did you upload the baked particles to sheep it?

Comment: Render farms have different ways to deal with baked simulations. Usually means you have to zip the cache folder along with the .blend file when uploading.  You might want to ask in the support forum for Sheepit directly.

Comment: i uploadet the whole project i guess ,, but should i somehow upload differently the baked dynamics thats what i liket to know,how to you zip cache ?